# Spark Normalizer Gives AssertionError: SparkContext should be initialized first?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, similarity, normalize

I'm running spark 1.4.1 and using pyspark.  Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Normalizer

def make_unit(x):
    nor = Normalizer()
    return (x[0], [x[1][0], x[1][1], x[1][2], nor.transform(x[1][3]),x[1][4]])

rdd_normal = rdd.map(make_unit)
```

rdd is a spark rdd of the form (a, [b, c, d, SparseVector, e]).

After running the above, I get this error:
"AssertionError: SparkContext should be initialized first".  I definitely have a sparkcontext running.  I'm able to do other things with my data and manipulate other rdds.  Yet, when I run the above code, it's telling me I don't have a running SC.  What am I doing wrong?

I just want to normalize the SparseVector so that I can do some cosine similarities.  I could calculate the dot product and divide by the norms, but I don't know if there is a built-in function for calculating norms.  Anyway, if I were to do nor.transform(v), where v is a SparseVector, I get the expected output.  However, when using this within a .map(), I get the above error.

Comment: That's OK.  I'm just could to use cosine = v1.dot(v2)/(v1.norm(2)*v2.norm(2)).  That works just fine.